# Why should we append zeros during CRC calculation?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, divisibility, coding-theory, binary

Say we have *M* as message bits , why do we need to append *r-zeros* to *M* message bits before performing the division to obtain r-bit checksum. Why don't we directly perform the division on the *M* message bits only (no zeros appended) and append the *r-bit* checksum at the end before transmission.

Answer (score 4):

Rewriting your question the way I understood it. Just to make sure that we are talking about the same thing. It is possible that I misunderstood, in which case this is rubbish.

Let $m(x)$ be the message polynomial, and $p(x)$ a CRC-polynomial of degree $r$.
Normally the CRC-tagged message is generated as follows. We calculate the remainder $r_1(x)$ of $x^rm(x)$ when divided by $p(x)$. The transmitted/stored version of the message is then $f(x)=x^rm(x)+r_1(x)$. Because $\deg r_1(x)\le r$, and the message polynomial was multiplied by $x^r$ (=padded with $r$ zeros)
the CRC-tag $r_1(x)$ does not overwrite any message bits.

The receiver can then perform the CRC-check simply by checking whether their
version of $f(x)$ is divisible by $p(x)$.

I understood that your suggestion is to just calculate the remainder $r_2(x)$ of
$m(x)$ when divided by $p(x)$, without padding the zeros, and then transmit the
pair $(m(x), r_2(x))$. The receiver can then check whether the polynomial formed by the last $r$ bits matches with the remainder of the message polynomial.

The reason why the standard way is better is the following. The CRC-polynomial
$p(x)$ can be designed in such a way that no binomial $x^{k_1}+x^{k_2}$ is divisible by it unless the exponents are very large (larger than the maximum allowed message length this CRC-polynomial comes with). For example, it is possible to select a degree 16 polynomial $p(x)$ in such a way that this never happens, when $k_1,k_2<2^{16}-1=65535$ - a relatively long block.

A consequence of this design is that ALL error patterns of two bits are caught.
Consider the following. If instead of $f(x)=x^rm(x)+r_1(x)$ the receiver makes two mistakes, he will see
$$f'(x)=f(x)+x^{k_1}+x^{k_2}$$
instead of $f(x)$. But because $f(x)$ is divisible by $p(x)$ and the extra binomial is not, he will notice that an error has happened, because $f'(x)$ is not divisible by $p(x)$.

But if we did it your way, the following bad thing might happen.
What if instead of a legal $(m(x),r_2(x))$ pair, the receiver makes, again, two errors, placed in a nasty way such that he sees instead of the above pair the pair
$$
(m(x)+x^j,r_2(x)+x^j),
$$
where $j<\deg p(x)$? Unfortunately they will not catch errors of this type.
That's because as
$$m(x)\equiv r_2(x)\pmod{p(x)},$$
we also have
$$
m(x)+x^j\equiv r_2(x)+x^j\pmod{p(x)},
$$
and hence this erroneous message passes this check even though only two bit errors occurred. Notice that we cannot improve this situation by redesigning the polynomial $p(x)$.

Algebraically the difference is that your method fails, when the same monomial error $x^j$ occurs in both the message and the check parts, as $x^j+x^j=0$. With zero padding in place that type of error will be caught because $p(x)$ does not divide any binomials. Zero padding means that divisibility by $p(x)$ will be tested with the error polynomial $x^{j+r}+x^j$ instead of the pair $(x^j,x^j)$.

Comment: Thanks Jyrki for your respone and time!!
I was actually tired searching and thinking for answer.

I am almost convinced with your reply but got struck at the lines
"_On the other hand, if we do it the usual way, this type of errors would get caught because even though 1+1=0 is divisible by p(x) the polynomial xr+1 is not!_ "

Could you please elaborate these lines. I did not get how you came down to 1+1 and x^r+1.

Comment: @john, I expanded and rewrote the later part(s) of my answer. Is it clearer now?

Comment: It is clearer now , Thank you very much Jyrki for your time. This is one strong reason where the traditional method beats the method suggested by me. But there could be other reasons as well , it would be great if others could chip in and respond where my method fails elsewhere.

Comment: Excuse me, but without going through mathematical proof, how would you explain this to a person without background in number theory e.g lets say, to an electronic engineer like me?

Comment: @quantum231 The same way Dilip explained it in his answer - he is teaching telcomm engineers professionally:-)

Answer (score 3):

To simplify @Jyrki's answer even further, suppose that $M(x)=1$, that is,
the $k-1 = \text{degree-}M$ high-order data bits are $0$.  Then, in the absence
of zero-padding, the division process that divides by $g(x)$ to give
the remainder $t(x)$ of degree smaller than $r$ simply returns $t(x) = 1$.
Transmitting $M(x)$ followed by $t(x)$ results in a codeword of
$$\underbrace{00\cdots01}_{k ~\text{data bits}}\,\underbrace{00\cdots 01}_{r~\text{parity bits}}$$
and so two errors could change the received sequence into the all-zeroes
sequence which will be happily accepted as a transmission with
no errors in it.

Comment: Agree with you Dilip , Thanks.